# Java Chessboard pieces not displaying corrrectly

Tags: java, image, chess

I am making a chess game for a class I have and the chess piece is not displaying correctly.

This is my code:

```
package SucksLego;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import SucksLego.CheesBoard.CaseEchiquier;
import lejos.nxt.ColorSensor.Color;

public class ChessBoard2 extends JFrame{

    private Container contents;

    private JButton [][] squares = new JButton [8][8];

    private int row = 7;
    private int col = 1;

    private ImageIcon piece = new ImageIcon ("chess-pawn-f.png");

    public ChessBoard2 (){

        super("Board");

        contents = getContentPane();
        contents.setLayout(new GridLayout (8,8));

        ButtonHandler buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                squares[i][j] = new JButton();


                if((i+j) % 2 != 0){
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(getBackground().BLACK);
                }

                contents.add(squares [i][j]);
                squares[i][j].addActionListener(buttonHandler);

            }
        }

        squares [row][col].setIcon (piece);

        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    private boolean isValidMove(int i, int j){

        System.out.println("I: " + i + " J: " + j);
        return true;

    }   

    private void processClick (int i, int j){

        if(isValidMove(i,j) == false){
            return;
        }

        squares[row][col].setIcon(null);
        squares[i][j].setIcon(piece);
        row=i;
        col=j;

    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Object source = e.getSource();

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                    if(source == squares[i][j]){
                        processClick(i,j);
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChessBoard2 chess = new ChessBoard2();
    }

}
```

The dimension of the icon is 60 x 60.

The icon is being displayed as a very small stip:

[image: chess board]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the image, change your code and add below code to your `ChessBoard2()` constructor under `super("Board");`

```
 try{
    URL resource = ChessBoard2.class.getClassLoader().getResource("chess-pawn-f.png");
    img = ImageIO.read(resource);
    piece = new ImageIcon(img);
 }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```